# How to categorize values in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe like below:

| city_company | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| London | Health Care |
| Seattle | Entrepreneurship |
| Copenhagen | Engineering |
| Melbourne | Law |
| Mountain View | b |
| Brisbane | c |
| San Francisco | d |

There are lots of groups for subject. I want to change b,c,d named by "Other". (Not only b,c,d, of course, n values..)
I want to use only these values: ["Health Care", "Entrepreneurship", "Engineering", "Law", "Other"]. If there are any different values , they should be changed by "Other".

| city_company | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| London | Health Care |
| Seattle | Entrepreneurship |
| Copenhagen | Engineering |
| Melbourne | Law |
| Mountain View | Other |
| Brisbane | Other |
| San Francisco | Other |

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the required values and replace them -

```py
import pandas as pd                                                                                                         
dd = {"city_company": ["London", "Seattle", "Copenhagen", "Melbourne", "Mountain View", "Brisbane", "San Francisco"],       
                                                                                                                            
"Subject": ["Health Care", "Entrepreneurship", "Engineering", "Law", "b", "c", "d"]                                         
                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                           
df = pd.DataFrame(dd)                                                                                                                                                                          
df.loc[~df['Subject'].isin( ["Health Care", "Entrepreneurship", "Engineering", "Law", "Other"]), ["Subject"]] = "Other"
```

Comment: There are not only b,c,d values in the dataframe that I want to change by "Other". There are maybe 500 other values.

Comment: Is there a way to identify them?

Comment: I want to use only these values: ["Health Care", "Entrepreneurship", "Engineering", "Law", "Other"]. If there are any different values , they should be changed by "Other".

Comment: In that case you can invert the selection - see my edited answer.

Comment: @Rebeka please edit this clarificaion into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
valid_subjects = ["Health Care", "Entrepreneurship", "Engineering", "Law"]
df["Subject"] = np.where(df["Subject"].isin(valid_subjects), df["Subject"], "Other")
```

```
    city_company           Subject
0         London       Health Care
1        Seattle  Entrepreneurship
2     Copenhagen       Engineering
3      Melbourne               Law
4  Mountain View             Other
5       Brisbane             Other
6  San Francisco             Other
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) method to transform the `"Subject"` column

```
df["Subject"] = df["Subject"].apply(lambda subject:"Other" if subject not in ["Health Care", "Entrepreneurship", "Engineering", "Law"] else subject)
```